# Issue when typing 'code .' in Ubuntu/WSL on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When running `code .` from Ubuntu/WSL in Windows 10, I receive the following error:

> `/mnt/c/Users/Agrock/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.63.13/scripts/wslCode.sh: 69: /home/helloagrock/.vscode-server-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/bin/code: not found`

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Reviewers - While this looks like a duplicate at first glance, and I can find *lots* of other *similar* questions, this one looks to be slightly different.  Enough so that I'm not marking it as a duplicate at least.  Let me know if I'm wrong and you can find a good duplicate.  Thanks!

Comment: And Agrock - Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I've provided an attempt at an answer below that I *think/hope* will work for you, but let me know if it doesn't and we can dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the WSL/VSCode server.  Since `code` is clearly in your path, it should be automatically reinstalled the next time you use it:

```
rm -rf .vscode-server/
```

Tested on my system to make sure there were no ill-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Agrock and welcome!

I too was experiencing this issue, I attempted NotTheDro01ds solution, but I also had to open VSCode in windows and then update the "Remote - WSL" extension manually in the vs code extensions marketplace.